# IntelliJ uses Java 11 even though 17 is configured

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a Gradle plugin that requires Java 17, using IntelliJ:

```
plugins {
  id("nu.studer.jooq") version "7.1.1"
}

// plugin config omitted
```

When running in the command line using `./gradlew run`, this all works fine. But when I run using IntelliJ, it gives

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: nu/studer/jooq/JooqPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

`java --version` output:

```
openjdk 17.0.4 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.4+8-Ubuntu-120.04)
```

In IntelliJ, under File -> Project Structure, the same JDK is configured both for Project Settings -> Project and for Platform Settings -> SDKs. IntelliJ version is 2022.2.1 (CE).

So, why is IntelliJ not using the configured Java version, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Check the settings on the Gradle tab of IntelliJ. Likely it has been configured to use an explicit JDK instead of using the project JDK.

Comment: That was it exactly! Thanks @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle and check what Gradle JVM points to.